# How to represent the Data Model of a Graph

Tags: graph, neo4j, data-modeling

So we have been developing some graph based analysis tools, using neo4j as a persistence engine in the background. As part of this we are developing a graph data model suitable for our domain, and we want to use this in the application layer to restrict the types of nodes, or to ensure that nodes of certain types must carry certain properties. Normal data model restrictions.

So thats the background, what I am asking is if there is some standard way to represent a data-model for a graph db? The graph equivalent of an xsd perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

There's an open-source project supporting strong schema definitions in Neo4j: Structr (http://structr.org, see it in action: http://vimeo.com/structr/videos)

[image: Structr's Visual Schema Editor]

With Structr, you can define an in-graph schema of your data model including

- Type inheritance
- Supported data types: Boolean, String, Integer, Long, Double, Date, Enum (+ values)
- Default values
- Cardinality (1:1, 1:*, *:1)
- Not-null constraints
- Uniqueness constraints
- Full type safety
- Validation
- Cardinality enforcement

Support for methods (custom action) is currently being added to the schema.

The schema can be edited with an editor, or directly via REST, modifiying the JSON representation of the data model:

```
{
   "query_time": "0.001618446",
   "result_count": 4,
   "result": [
      {
         "name": "Whisky",
         "extendsClass": null,
         "relatedTo": [
            {
               "id": "96d05ddc9f0b42e2801f06afb1374458",
               "name": "Flavour"
            },
            {
               "id": "28f85dca915245afa3782354ea824130",
               "name": "Location"
            }
         ],
         "relatedFrom": [],
         "id": "df9f9431ed304b0494da84ef63f5f2d8",
         "type": "SchemaNode",
         "_name": "String"
      },
      {
         "name": "Flavour",
         ...
      },
      {
         "name": "Location",
         ...
      },
      {
         "name": "Region",
         ...
      }
   ],
   "serialization_time": "0.000829985"
}

{
   "query_time": "0.001466743",
   "result_count": 3,
   "result": [
      {
         "name": null,
         "sourceId": "28f85dca915245afa3782354ea824130",
         "targetId": "e4139c5db45a4c1cbfe5e358a84b11ed",
         "sourceMultiplicity": null,
         "targetMultiplicity": "1",
         "sourceNotion": null,
         "targetNotion": null,
         "relationshipType": "LOCATED_IN",
         "sourceJsonName": null,
         "targetJsonName": null,
         "id": "d43902ad7348498cbdebcd92135926ea",
         "type": "SchemaRelationship",
         "relType": "IS_RELATED_TO"
      },
      {
         "name": null,
         "sourceId": "df9f9431ed304b0494da84ef63f5f2d8",
         "targetId": "96d05ddc9f0b42e2801f06afb1374458",
         "sourceMultiplicity": null,
         "targetMultiplicity": "1",
         "sourceNotion": null,
         "targetNotion": null,
         "relationshipType": "HAS_FLAVOURS",
         "sourceJsonName": null,
         "targetJsonName": null,
         "id": "bc9a6308d1fd4bfdb64caa355444299d",
         "type": "SchemaRelationship",
         "relType": "IS_RELATED_TO"
      },
      {
         "name": null,
         "sourceId": "df9f9431ed304b0494da84ef63f5f2d8",
         "targetId": "28f85dca915245afa3782354ea824130",
         "sourceMultiplicity": null,
         "targetMultiplicity": "1",
         "sourceNotion": null,
         "targetNotion": null,
         "relationshipType": "PRODUCED_IN",
         "sourceJsonName": null,
         "targetJsonName": null,
         "id": "a55fb5c3cc29448e99a538ef209b8421",
         "type": "SchemaRelationship",
         "relType": "IS_RELATED_TO"
      }
   ],
   "serialization_time": "0.000403616"
}
```

You can access nodes and relationships stored in Neo4j as JSON objects through a RESTful API which is dynamically configured based on the in-graph schema.

```
$ curl try.structr.org:8082/structr/rest/whiskies?name=Ardbeg
{
   "query_time": "0.001267211",
   "result_count": 1,
   "result": [
      {
         "flavour": {
            "name": "J",
            "description": "Full-Bodied, Dry, Pungent, Peaty and Medicinal, with Spicy, Feinty Notes.",
            "id": "626ba892263b45e29d71f51889839ebc",
            "type": "Flavour"
         },
         "location": {
            "region": {
               "name": "Islay",
               "id": "4c7dd3fe2779492e85bdfe7323cd78ee",
               "type": "Region"
            },
            "whiskies": [
               ...
            ],
            "name": "Port Ellen",
            "latitude": null,
            "longitude": null,
            "altitude": null,
            "id": "47f90d67e1954cc584c868e7337b6cbb",
            "type": "Location"
         },
         "name": "Ardbeg",
         "id": "2db6b3b41b70439dac002ba2294dc5e7",
         "type": "Whisky"
      }
   ],
   "serialization_time": "0.010824154"
}
```

In the UI, there's also a data editing (CRUD) tool, and CMS components supporting to create web applications on Neo4j.

Disclaimer: I'm a developer of Structr and founder of the project.

Comment: @Axel - When posting answers such as this, remember to disclose your association with the structr.org project.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits The in-graph schema contains the additional information about cardinality. On each schema change, all schema meta information are transformed into Java code, compiled and injected into the JVM. The cardinality enforcement is implemented in structr-core, an OGM library around Neo4j.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Sorry, added a disclaimer.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no standard way to do this.  Indeed, even if there were, keep in mind that the only constraints that neo4j currently supports are [uniqueness constraints](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-constraints.html).

Take for example some sample rules:

- All nodes labeled `:Person` must have non-empty properties `fname` and `lname`
- All nodes labeled `:Person` must have >= 1 outbound relationship of type `:works_for`

The trouble with the present neo4j is that even in the case where you did have a schema language (standardized) that could express these things, there wouldn't be a way that the db engine itself could actually enforce that constraint.

So the simple answer is no, there's no standard way of doing that right now.

A few tricks I've seen people use to simulate the same:

1. Assemble a list of "test suite" cypher queries, with known results.  Query for things you know shouldn't be there; non-empty result sets are a sign of a problem/integrity violation.   Query for things you know should be there; empty result sets are a problem.
2. Application-level control -- via some layer like spring-data or similar, control who can talk to the database.  This essentially moves your data integrity/testing problem up into the app, away from the database.

It's a common (and IMHO annoying) aspect of many NoSQL solutions (not specifically neo4j) that because of their schema-weakness, they tend to force validation up the tech stack into the application.  Doing these things in the application tends to be harder and more error-prone.   SQL databases permit you to implement all sorts of schema constraints, triggers, etc -- specifically to make it really damn hard to put the wrong data into the database.  The NoSQL databases typically either aren't there yet, or don't do this as a design decision.   There are indeed flexibility/performance tradeoffs.  Databases can insert faster and be more flexible to adapt quickly if they aren't burdened with checking each atom of data against a long list of schema rules.

**EDIT**: Two relevant resources: the [metagraphs proposal](http://gist.neo4j.org/?8640853) talks about how you could represent the schema as a graph, and [neoprofiler](https://github.com/moxious/neoprofiler/) is an application that attempts to infer the *actual* structure of a neo4j database and show you its "profile".

With time, I think it's reasonable to hope that neo would include basic integrity features like requiring certain labels to have certain properties (the example above), restricting the data types of certain properties (lname must always be a String, never an integer), and so on.   The graph data model is a bit wild and wooly though (in the computational complexity sense) and there are some constraints on graphs that people desperately would want, but will probably never get.   An example would be the constraint that a graph can't have cycles in it.  Enforcing that on the creation of every relationship would be very computationally intensive.  (

Comment: So yes, we are doing it in the application layer. The "application" is really a server which takes requests to match graph templates via a webservice, or to add graphs to the database. Internally it validates these requests and parses them into Cypher. However, we would like to be able to reuse the software in different domains by just swapping out the schema, but we have no intuitive way to build or represent such a schema other than by hand.

Comment: To build/represent the schema, I'd recommend the "metagraph" proposal (linked in my answer).  It's a reasonably solid proposal, and I don't know of better suggestions right now.  Also, please remember to mark this as accepted if it's the answer you sought.